# Check if text file contains something with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do you check if a file on the server contains a certain text ? So far this is what I've done:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('myfile.txt', function(data) {
   if (data == "Hello World") {
    alert("Hello World is found");
   }
   else {
    alert("It's NOT found");
   }
}, 'text');
</script>
```

This is `myfile.txt`:

```
Blah blah blah
It's a good day.
Have a nice day everyone.
Hello World.
```

That script keeps returning `It's NOT found` even though the file contains `Hello World` How can I fix that ?

**UPDATE:**
That answer works but now I want to check it every second with `setInterval` but it doesn't work after I get rid of `Hello World` in `myfile.txt` it still shows `Hello World is found` even though it's not there anymore. This is what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$.get('myfile.txt', function(data) {
   if (data.indexOf("Hello World")>-1){
    document.write("Hello World is found");
   }
   else {
    document.write("It's NOT found");
   }
}, 'text');}, 1000);
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2:** This is my code in response to @Stuart's answer

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        $.get("myfile.txt"
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.indexOf("Hello World")>-1){
                    document.write("Hello World is found");
                }
                else {
                    document.write("It's NOT found");
                }
            }
        )
    })
});
```

On my Console it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

How do I fix that? Sorry I'm still learning about Javascript

**UPDATE 3:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$.get('myfile.txt',{cache:false} function(data) {
   if (data.indexOf("Hello World")>-1){
    document.write("Hello World is found");
   }
   else {
    document.write("It's NOT found");
   }
}, 'text');}, 1000);
</script>
```

I get this in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and my browser doesn't show anything.

Comment: "*That script keeps returning It's NOT found*" - how many times have you tried? What's the value if `data` in your attempts? What do you expect to happen when you compare that to your string?

Comment: To the update: The file is probably being cached. Use [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead and pass `cache:false` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf instead of ==. You are testing if the entire text equals hello world.

```
if (textdata.indexOf(stringToFind)>-1){ do stuff }
```

EDIT, question has morphed, code example:

```
function getTextfile()
{
  $.get('myfile.txt', {cache:false}, function(data) 
  {
    if (data.indexOf("Hello World")>-1) {
      document.write("Hello World is found");
    }
    else {
      document.write("It's NOT found");
    } 
    setTimeout(getTextfile, 1000);
 });
} 

getTextfile();
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I encounter another problem, please read my updated post above

Comment: You're reading the same file in every second, you don't need to do that surely? What is it you're trying to do..?

Comment: I have a local web page on my router that shows the log of my openvpn connection, I want to play a sound notification every time my openvpn gets connected / disconnected. The way to find out whether it's connected / disconnected is through reading the openvpn log file and see if there's a certain text matches the log file.

Comment: I see, have you tried cache:false? It sounds like it could be that each request is a cached response, hence seemingly seeing hello world each time...   If cache:false doesn't do it, try appending a random query string to the URL you're fetching, so each request is fresh.

Comment: Could you rewrite your code ? I've tried `cache:false` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Rewrite my code? You mean your code!? :) Show us where and how you've tried, post the code and we can see to getting you working. (You passed {cache:false} as settings for your Ajax request yes? Did you try appending a random string? Look in the console/dev tools network panel to see if each successive request is returned from the cache or not at least.

Comment: Please see `UPDATE 2`

Comment: syntax is all over the place, just do your settings in the $.get, no need for the outer $.ajax. Look at the manual page for it https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Please see `UPDATE 3`

Comment: You are missing a comma after {cache:false}  ...! :)

Comment: I changed it to `$.get('testfile.txt', {cache:false}, function(data) {` but it still doesn't refresh automatically. I get this in the console `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded VM6853:47`

Comment: Are you sure you're not in a infinite loop somewhere? What's the full code look like at this stage?

Comment: Use setTimout instead, and wrap your code in a function:    Edited my answer above to post code instead.    

function getTextfile()
{
   $.get('myfile.txt', {cache:false}, function(data) 
   {
      if (data.indexOf("Hello World")>-1) {
         document.write("Hello World is found");
      }
      else {
         document.write("It's NOT found");
      }
   });
}
setTimout(getTextfile, 1000);

Comment: Still not working, the text on the browser still doesn't automatically change when I get rid of `Hello World` This is the script http://pastebin.com/esDWqRNU this is the text file: http://pastebin.com/7djtr76R

Comment: See the code in my edited answer. The code pasted in the previous comment isn't complete.

Comment: In your last line, you mispelled `setTimeout` with `setTimout` but unfortunately it still doesn't work, I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` http://pastebin.com/MXcUvrA6

Comment: Argh I was pasting in on iPad, I've amended the above. Just call the function once initially, that setTimeout only belongs inside, so it calls itself - forever mind, which is likely the cause of the call stack exceeded error anyway....

Comment: It still doesn't work, I still get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` if you're not away from your computer please run this code to see if it works for you http://pastebin.com/j6MVyHaj

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the whole text is equal to the string "Hello world".

Use String.indexOf, like this:

```
$.get('myfile.txt', function(data) {
   if (data.indexOf("Hello world") !== -1) {
   alert("Hello World is found");
   }
   else {
    alert("It's NOT found");
   }
}, 'text');
```

By the way, golden rule of javascript: console.log everything. You will then understand the structure and the way jQuery for example makes response objects, don't use alert when trying to debug.

Comment: Can you take a look at my updated post, I want to refresh it every second but my code still doesn't work

Comment: I too believe it is cache, did you try something like this: $.get('myfile.txt' + "?" + $.now() ?